# How to find out what processes have folder or file locked?

Tags: .net-3.5, filesystems, filelock

How do you go about querying running processes to find out what folders or files they have locked? (i.e. you go to eject a drive and you're told that it can't be ejected because it's in use)

I'd like to either get an "off the shelf" download, or write a .NET 3.5 app to do this (primarily a Windows question).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225802/how-to-determine-which-process-is-holding-a-file-in-windows

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) will show you this. Ctrl-F will let you search for a file and list the process(es) that have that file open/locked. You can then close that handle using Process Explorer.

There's also a command line utility called `oh.exe` available for download. See [here](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/processlock.htm) for more details

Comment: Process Expolorer is my tool of choice for this. It also allows you to close the handle.

Comment: Good point re. the handle closing. I'd forgotten that. Answer amended

Comment: However, don't close the handle unless you're willing to have the program crash, freeze, burn your house down or hold all your data ransom. The program won't expect the handle to close until it decides to close it, so who knows what havoc it will cause when this assumption is violated :)

Answer (score 5):

[LockHunter](http://lockhunter.com/) is a great context menu tool for Windows.

Comment: Good tool - just does what it says!

Comment: This is good when you don't know which file in a folder has a lock.  It will tell you the locks on any files within a folder or drive.

Answer (score 2):

One of the first things I put on my Windows dev machines is [WhoUses](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/processesmodules/print.php/c2827).  It's nice because it's open source too.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/ (freeware) has a special UI for exactly this situation.